# How to catch authorization fail, clear cookies and request access again

Tags: c#, google-api, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have created a simple web application using Asp .net core 3 with the Google api .net client library.  This example just requests a users profile information from the People api.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        
        // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
        services
            .AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
                // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
                // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
                o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
                // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
                o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
            });
        
        
    }
```

Controler

```
    [GoogleScopedAuthorize(PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.UserinfoProfile)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserProfile([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
    {

        var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
        var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = cred
        });

        var request = service.People.Get("people/me");
        request.PersonFields = "names,emailAddresses";
        var person = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        return View(person);

    }
```

This works fine and authorizes the user however. If i then go to [google permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and remove the apps access.

[image]

and run the application again i get

> GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]
> Errors [
> Message[Invalid Credentials] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[authError] Domain[global]
> ]
> Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)

If i clear the cookies on the page it will work again and request access.  Im not sure if this is an issue with the library or if there is a way for me to catch this error and force a clear of the cookies and then run the authorization again.

I have cross posted this as an issue on the [Google api .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1816) in the event its a bug in the libary.

## clear cookies

I managed to catch the error in a catch (GoogleApiException e).  Then I tried clearing the cookies, and then running the code again it doesn't appear to actually clear them.  So the error is the same.

```
foreach (var cookie in HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
            }
```

## update

No change the cookies don't appear to get deleted so i just get the error message again.

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(PeopleServiceService.ScopeConstants.UserinfoProfile)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserProfile([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
    {
        Person person;
        PeopleServiceService service;
        try
        {
            var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
            service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = cred
            });
        

        var request = service.People.Get("people/me");
        request.PersonFields = "names,emailAddresses";
        person = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        }
        catch (GoogleApiException e)
        {
            foreach (var cookie in HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
            }
            
            var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
            service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = cred
            });

            var request = service.People.Get("people/me");
            request.PersonFields = "names,emailAddresses";
            person = await request.ExecuteAsync();
        }
        return View(person);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping in a try-catch and then doing the clear or redirect when you get the expected exception?

Comment: I can catch it but my attempt to clear them has not worked as of yet.